# Checking Values Against of an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm creating my own tagging "thingy" which will function similar to Stack Overflow's.

However, my tags require me to check against two categories(arrays), `AmericanCodes` and `CanadianCodes`. If the tag does not exist in either of the two arrays, I need to deal with it differently.

Everything seems to be working fine, with the exception of my `$.inArray` functionality.

It is acting as if it is found in the first array every time. (You'll see what i mean when you view the Fiddle)

Here is my code: Fiddle link below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var AmericanCodes = ["AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF"]; // Known american conversion codes
    var CanadianCodes = ["CA", "CB", "CC", "CD", "CE", "CF"]; // Known canadian conversion codes
    var UnknownCodes = []; // Collects Unrecognized Codes
    var Entry = $("input#RecessiveCodes"); // Set Input
    $(Entry).keypress(function (e) { // 
        if (e.keyCode == 32) { // This is the enter key
            var EntryValue = $(Entry).val(); // Get Input
            console.log(EntryValue);
            if ($.inArray(EntryValue, AmericanCodes) < 0) { // Check if it's an american code
                $("ul#EnteredCodes").append("<li class='AR'>", EntryValue, "</li>") // Style knowns slightly different than unkown
            } else if ($.inArray(EntryValue, CanadianCodes) < 0) { // Check if it's an canadian code
                $("ul#EnteredCodes").append("<li class='CR'>", EntryValue, "</li>") // Style knowns slightly different than unkown
            } else {
                UnknownCodes.push($(EntryValue)); //Add to list but store unknown reccessive seperatley
                $("ul#EnteredCodes").append("<li class='UR'>", EntryValue, "</li>") // Style unknowns slightly different
            }
            $(Entry).val("");
        }
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gj8dp/)

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.inArray(...)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) returns `-1` if the value **doesn't** appear in the array.

So:

```
if ($.inArray(EntryValue, AmericanCodes) < 0)
```

only matches if `EntryValue` **does not** exist in `AmericanCodes`.

- Try `>= 0` instead.

Couple of other things (maybe just from making the JSFiddle too quickly!):

- You've put the CSS as `li.AR` three times, instead of `li.AR`, `li.CR` and `li.UR`.
- `e.keyCode == 32` checks for the <kbd>space</kbd> key, not <kbd>enter</kbd>!
- If you are using <kbd>space</kbd> not <kbd>enter</kbd>, your `$(Entry).val("")` at the end of the function won't work because the `keypress` event is called BEFORE the most recently typed character was pressed, so the `space` key will be applied AFTER the text field is emptied. You probably want to use `keyup`, which is called after the keypress, but then remember to use `trimRight()` to remove the space character from the `input` before passing it to `$.inArray`.
- `Event` is already a jQuery object, so wrapping it as `$(Event)` is redundant and just wastes a few cycles.

Working JSFiddle with all these changes: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gj8dp/5/)